# How do I declare that a function dies so it is detected by PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

## Background

I use several helper functions to stop the program flow and return data. For example, while most pages are HTML I occasionally return JSON and call

```
/**
 * @param array|bool $response
 *
 * @die
 */
function jsonResponseDie($response)
{
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($response);
  die();
}
```

## The Problem

However, the calling function does not detect that there is a die statement and allows code to be present after it without warning.

```
function recievePush()
{
  // Process a push request and respond with a json array.

  jsonResponseDie(array('status' => TRUE));
  echo 'This will never execute but PhpStorm doesn\'t know that';
}
```

## The Question

How do I get PhpStorm to detect this function will die?

I did try a few items "@return die" or "@die" but these do not appear to be recognized. I also reviewed some documentation [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html) but found nothing useful.

Comment: Add a die() Statement after jsonResponseDie() ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no special tags for such stuff in PHPDoc. PhpStorm also does not have any solution to that yet.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10673 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**UPDATE 2020-10-20:**
The aforementioned ticket [has been implemented](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10673#focus=Comments-27-3775062.0-0) and such functionality is now available since **PhpStorm 2020.1.x** version.

It is implemented using **Advanced Metadata functionality** (by creating separate PHP-like file for IDE eyes only): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#define-exit-points

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    exitPoint(\App\PageFlow::exitApplication());
}
```

Another example: as a result, the `terminate()` call with the `bar` argument provided will act as an exit point (another value will not trigger this). The last line of the run method will therefore be treated as unreachable:

```
exitPoint(Application::terminate('bar'));
```

[image]

---

**P.S.** From PhpStorm 2020.3 (to be released at some point in December or so this year) and using PHP Language Level = 8.0 you will be able to use **PHP 8-style attribute** `#[NoReturn]` right in your code instead of separate Advanced Metadata file (see [WI-55531 (actual/original implementation)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-55531) and [WI-56103 (new attribute name)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56103) tickets).

Answer (score 0):

I have a CodeIgniter 3.1.11 project that I wanted to implement an exitPoint on my `SendJsonResponseAndDie()` method which is in my `myproject/ci/application/helpers/format_helper.php` file.

For me, the solution was as simple as creating a `meta` directory in `myproject`, then creating a `.phpstorm.meta.php` file with the following contents:

**myproject/meta/.phpstorm.meta.php**:

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {

    function exitPoint($functionReference) {
        return "exitPoint " . $functionReference;
    }

    exitPoint(\SendJsonResponseAndDie());
}
```

Hey presto, the "unreachable statement" text appears whenever I mouseover code that occurs after the function call anywhere in the project.

I wish, though, that the lines of code that cannot be reached would be dimmed so that I am visually drawn to the problem instead of requiring my hover event.

Some additional reading not mentioned in @LazyOne's answer: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/meta/.phpstorm.meta.php